# COPIANDO UM REPOSITORIO PARA OUTRO

Tags: git

Boa Tarde,
Pessoal estou trabalhando em uma empresa onde estamos num processo de mudança, tinhamos um repositorio GIT no ar interno aqui na empresa que toda noite atualiza a MASTER com o repositorio master que fica no cliente, porem devido as novas orientações devemos não utilizar mais esse repositorio da empresa e sim diretamente o repositorio do cliente.
Minha duvida, tenho um monte de branch no repositorio da minha empresa, e alguns deles não subiu ainda para a master do cliente.
Gostaria de de alguma forma copiar todos os branchs que tenho norepositorio da minha empresa para o repositorio do cliente, afim de manter todos os historicos de branchs.

imagina que tenho dois links

http://minhaempresa/git/master
http://cliente/git/master
a ideia é copias todos os branches do link minha empresa para o link cliente, sem copiar a master e develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O GIT é um repositório distribuído, sendo possível simplesmente fazer push para um servidor qualquer. Sendo assim, os passos para "migrar" de um servidor para o outro pode ser simplesmente fazer um push para o novo servidor da sua própria máquina.

Caso o repo não exista localmente:

```
git clone <URL_SERVIDOR_ATUAL>
cd <NOME_DO_REPOSITÓRIO>
```

Faça o checkout em cada branch que se pretende "migrar".

```
git checkout <NOME_DA_BRANCH>
```

Para percorrer todas as branches vc pode tentar algo como: (*não testei esta parte!*)

```
for remote in $(git branch -r); do
if [[ "${remote}" != "origin/HEAD" ]]; then
git checkout ${remote:7}
fi
done
```

Pegue também as tags, se desejar:

```
git fetch --tags
```

Troque um *origin* pelo outro:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <URL_SERVIDOR_NOVO>
```

Envie tudo para o novo *origin*:

```
git push origin --all
git push --tags
```